# Web Application does not update database at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have the following table:

```
|   product_no    |   product_name   |   price  |
=================================================
|    10000        |   teapot         |   5.00   |
|    10001        |   grasspot       |   2.00   |
|    10002        |   glasspot       |  10.00   |
|    10003        |   jackpot        |  15.00   |
```

I have two text field - `m_pname` and `m_pprice`.

These two field will display the product name and price when a user select the product name from a drop down list - `dropdownlist1`

Both text field are editable such that when a user edit them and click on a `Modify` button `Button4`, the button will update the database.

However, here come the problem - the database is **not** updated and also, the `dropdownlist1` still reflect the old value.

The `dropdownlist1` have the `Autopostback` checkbox checked.

So, I was wondering if this is caused by the `Autopostback` checkbox.

Some of the code is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectDB("Data Source=WR2\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testbase;Integrated Security=True");

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader testtable = SQLReadCommand(conn, "Select * from testtable where product_no='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'");

        if (testtable.HasRows)
        {
            while (testtable.Read())
            {
                m_pname.Text = testtable["product_name"].ToString();
                m_pprice.Text = testtable["price"].ToString();

                modify_status.Text = modify_status.Text + "[ Name: " + m_pname.Text + " Price: " + m_pprice.Text + " ]";
            }
        }
        testtable.Close();

        //modify_status.Text = "";
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
       modify_status.Text = err.Message;
    }
}

protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectDB("Data Source=WR2\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testbase;Integrated Security=True");

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        String vpname = m_pname.Text;

        SQLWriteCommand(conn, "UPDATE testtable SET product_name = '" + m_pname.Text + "', price = " + m_pprice.Text + " WHERE product_no = " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

        modify_status.Text = "Changed " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + " to " + vpname;
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        modify_status.Text = err.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on button you re-bind dropdownlist and so selected value is lost and replaced with first item of dropdownlist.

you can adjust your databind in your page load

```
if(! IsPostBack)
{
   //Bind of datas

}
```

And so when you post data, you don't erase selected value

Nota : selectedValue is persisted with ViewState

Comment: I tried putting the code in my page load but it return me `Property accessor 'SelectedValue' on object 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' threw the following exception:'Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.'`

Comment: you must specify SelectedValue on your DropDownList, ensure that you don't use GridView control, because gridview don't have SelectedValue property

Comment: At last I did it. I created another function (I name it as `LoadDatabase`) containing the same code as the Page_Load and after the page_load completed its work. There is a button that will run the `LoadDatabase` and now it is working correctly. Well done.